# Is there a replacement or even upgrade possible for my worn out SM Audio Pro Passive Volume Controller?

Tags: audio, identification, potentiometer

I own a passive audio volume controller for my studio speakers. It is lightweight, small footprint and did do a great job until recently. Now the potentiometer seems to be completely worn out, there is lost contact, crackling, weird value jumps.

As I'm into repairing electronics stuff instead of throwing it away, especially when it did a great job so far, I opened the device and found some information on the potentiometer. But I lack the knowledge to find a proper replacement, or to be even a bit certain about what to look for. The information I could gather so far is the following:

- the potentiometer seems to be 4 channel (makes sense, as it controls two stereo symmetric audio lines, XLR or 5mm Jack Plug)
- first print I found says "A5K". Axial 5 kOhm?
- second print: "LF7.928-1GRa"
- third print: "080109002"
- on the bottom side it is mounted with 4 times 3 through hole connectors

Is that enough information to get a proper replacement?

If not, can I gather more information from the hardware? Here's some pictures I took:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit away the part where you seek where to buy this or equivalent pot - it's off topic. Please limit to just find help identifying the part - it's on topic.

Comment: Have you tried spraying some contact cleaner into the pot yet?

Comment: Contact cleaner: first thing I tried. Did work the last three times, but everything has an end, it seems...

Answer (score 1):

The colour indcates it might be from a maufacturer that makes pots with that colour, but it also might just be a chinese clone made to look like a quality pot.

A5K would indicate a 5K pot resistance, and the A means a specific resistance curve - but A might mean logarithmic or linear curve depending on manufacturer. You might be able to verify this with a multimeter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a couple of links that may help you find a replacement. The first link is the datasheet. The second one is the search result for that series.

https://www.bourns.com/data/global/pdfs/PTD90.pdf

https://www.bourns.com/search?indexCatalogue=psindex&searchQuery=ptd90*

Good luck.

Comment: Does 4cup in the description mean it has 4 "channels"? (Sorry for using channels, most likely not the correct ee term). Then there is none with 5kOhm, can I just use one with 10kOhm? What would the consequences be?

Comment: It looks like "cups" is the number of sections (you need 4). You need to make the part number according to the datasheet (page 3). Of course, this doesn't mean that the combination of features in you part number will be available.